# Recurring Google-/Microsoft-/Typeform or other form that shows answer from previous entries

Tags: google-forms, typeform, odk, microsoft-forms, kobotoolbox

I would like to set up a survey/form that I can repeatedly send to the field (I'm working in NGO business) with mainly open answer questions. The form should be done in a way that it always already shows the answers from when the form was filled the previous time. Anyone knows sth like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODK and KoBoToolbox support that feature. It is not yet documented on XLSForm.org, but you can read more about it here: https://docs.getodk.org/form-logic/#values-from-the-last-saved-record